# Android Check for response HTTP

Tags: java, android, rest, android-studio, okhttp

I am using OKHTTP to make api calls and I realize I can use .enque for async calls and .execute for sync calls.

is there a callback to check whether the response has been received without breaking the UI or the flow of the application.

I am using the following code:

```
public void getItems() {


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                String url = "https://beta-pp-api.polkadoc.com/v1.0/products?category=CP&available_via=mail_order";
                {
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(url)
                            .addHeader("Authorization", token)
                            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                            .addHeader("X-Service-Code", "PP")
                            .get()
                            .build();

                    try {
                        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                        groupList=getPills(response);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
        }).start();
```

for getPills

```
public ArrayList<Group> getPills(Response response) throws JSONException {

        try
        {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<Child> childList;
        ArrayList<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<Group>();


        if (jsonArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                Group group = new Group();
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                group.setPillName((String) jsonObject.get("title"));
                id = jsonObject.get("id").toString();

                //second api call
                getPillInfo(id);


                try {

                    JSONObject NewJSONObject = new JSONObject(secondResponse.body().string());
                    group.setSamePillAsData((String) NewJSONObject.getJSONObject("details").get("same_as"));
                    group.setPillType((String) NewJSONObject.getJSONObject("details").get("pill_type_short"));
                    childList = new ArrayList<Child>();
                    Child child = new Child();
                    child.setSideEffectData((String) NewJSONObject.getJSONObject("details").get("side_effects_short"));
                    child.setPriceData((String) NewJSONObject.getJSONObject("details").get("cost_short"));
                    child.setPillChoiceData((String) NewJSONObject.getJSONObject("details").get("criteria_short"));
                    childList.add(child);
                    group.setItems(childList);

                    groupList.add(group);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }
            }
        return groupList;

    }
```

for get pillInfo():

```
public void getPillInfo(String id) {


                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                String url = "https://beta-pp-api.polkadoc.com/v1.0/products/" + id;

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .addHeader("Authorization", token)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("X-Service-Code", "PP")
                        .get()
                        .build();

                try {
                    secondResponse = client.newCall(request).execute();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

    }
```

My UI is breaking everytime. What is going on?

Comment: If you want to monitor the http request and response. Try to use stetho http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ It can be used in a quick way with few statement in your code. And the most important is, it can be used in OKHTTP client. After you used it, you can monitor the http request and response of your application using the chrome features.

Comment: Can you post your logcat messages?

Comment: Hi all! thanks for the quick replies. I am getting the response now however, since it is not on the main thread, I am getting inconsistencies. For example, My response is coming AFTER my UI is loaded. Should I use an OVERLAY and wait for say 5-10 seconds before loading UI?